# Construct a Javascript object with a complex structure?

Tags: javascript, constructor

I have an Object with this structure that I instantiate all around the code

```
costs: {
    totalPerYear,
    totalEver,

    perMonth: {
        items: {
            depreciation,
            insurance,
            credit,
            inspection,
            roadTaxes,
            fuel,
            maintenance,
            repairsImprovements,
            parking,
            tolls,
            fines,
            washing
        },
        standingCosts,
        runningCosts,
        total
    },

    perUnitDistance: { 
        runningCosts,
        totalCosts
    }
}
```

I've been [reading about constructors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) and [instantiation](https://medium.com/dailyjs/instantiation-patterns-in-javascript-8fdcf69e8f9b). Is there a way, for the sake of *conciseness*, to have a constructor for this object wherein all the variables are set to `undefined`, like what happens when we define a variable `var x;`?

I have the obvious solution

```
function Costs(){
    this.totalPerYear = undefined;
    this.totalEver = undefined;

    this.perMonth = {
        items: {
            depreciation: undefined,
            insurance: undefined,
            credit: undefined,
            inspection: undefined,
            roadTaxes: undefined,
            fuel: undefined,
            maintenance: undefined,
            repairsImprovements: undefined,
            parking: undefined,
            tolls: undefined,
            fines: undefined,
            washing: undefined                        
        },
        standingCosts: undefined,
        runningCosts: undefined,
        total: undefined
    };

    this.perUnitDistance = { 
        runningCosts: undefined,
        totalCosts: undefined
    };
};

var userCosts = new Costs();
```

Which techniques do you use to create an object with a complex structure?

Comment: `this.totalPerYear: undefined` is not valid syntax. `:` should be `=`.

Comment: Do you need the object to have any particular prototype?

Comment: @Barmar you're right, amended accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want an object and don't need it to have a special prototype, a function returning an object rather than a constructor is quite straightforward:

```
function costs() {
    return {
        costs: {
            totalPerYear: undefined,
            totalEver: undefined,

            perMonth: {
                items: {
                    depreciation: undefined,
                    insurance: undefined,
                    credit: undefined,
                    inspection: undefined,
                    roadTaxes: undefined,
                    fuel: undefined,
                    maintenance: undefined,
                    repairsImprovements: undefined,
                    parking: undefined,
                    tolls: undefined,
                    fines: undefined,
                    washing: undefined
                },
                standingCosts: undefined,
                runningCosts: undefined,
                total: undefined
            },

            perUnitDistance: { 
                runningCosts: undefined,
                totalCosts: undefined
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Example:

```js
function costs() {
    return {
        costs: {
            totalPerYear: undefined,
            totalEver: undefined,

            perMonth: {
                items: {
                    depreciation: undefined,
                    insurance: undefined,
                    credit: undefined,
                    inspection: undefined,
                    roadTaxes: undefined,
                    fuel: undefined,
                    maintenance: undefined,
                    repairsImprovements: undefined,
                    parking: undefined,
                    tolls: undefined,
                    fines: undefined,
                    washing: undefined
                },
                standingCosts: undefined,
                runningCosts: undefined,
                total: undefined
            },

            perUnitDistance: { 
                runningCosts: undefined,
                totalCosts: undefined
            }
        }
    };
}

console.log(costs());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

There is, of course, nothing to prevent your giving yourself a shorter name to use within `costs`:

```
function costs() {
    const u = undefined;
    return {
        costs: {
            totalPerYear: u,
            totalEver: u,

            perMonth: {
                items: {
                    depreciation: u,
                    insurance: u,
                    credit: u,
                    inspection: u,
                    roadTaxes: u,
                    fuel: u,
                    maintenance: u,
                    repairsImprovements: u,
                    parking: u,
                    tolls: u,
                    fines: u,
                    washing: u
                },
                standingCosts: u,
                runningCosts: u,
                total: u
            },

            perUnitDistance: { 
                runningCosts: u,
                totalCosts: u
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Example:

```js
function costs() {
    const u = undefined;
    return {
        costs: {
            totalPerYear: u,
            totalEver: u,

            perMonth: {
                items: {
                    depreciation: u,
                    insurance: u,
                    credit: u,
                    inspection: u,
                    roadTaxes: u,
                    fuel: u,
                    maintenance: u,
                    repairsImprovements: u,
                    parking: u,
                    tolls: u,
                    fines: u,
                    washing: u
                },
                standingCosts: u,
                runningCosts: u,
                total: u
            },

            perUnitDistance: { 
                runningCosts: u,
                totalCosts: u
            }
        }
    };
}

console.log(costs());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira and I think an object literal like this ^ would be more performant too.

Comment: I thought he was looking for a way to avoid having to write `: undefined` on every line. Maybe some way to do this with destructuring assignment?

Comment: @Barmar - Oh, that's a fun thought. I'm not sure it works, but give it a go!

Comment: Actually, that seems better suited to the constructor. `{this.a, this.b, ...} = {}`

Comment: @Barmar - You can't destructure into properties like that, only variables.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid repeating `undefined`, like `return{a, b};`. I think I've seen that somewhere?

Comment: @Barmar, you need something like `({ a: this.a, b: this.b } = object);`

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira - Yes, but then instead of repeating `undefined`, you find yourself repeating the name of the property: `let foo; return {foo};` :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the shorter name technique is really cool :) Thanks

Comment: Anyway, it should exist a function somewhere to instantiate an object with said structure with all properties to undefined, like if we were simply putting `var x;`.